# Finding the general solution of a linear differential equation when there is just y' given

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The formulation of the problem is as following:

$$(\cos x) * y' = \cos x + 2\sin x$$

Since this is a linear differential of the first order, and I'm looking for a general solution, the aim is to find $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$.

Since there is just $y'$, I thought $P(x)$ would be zero. However, the official solution of the equation is

$$y=(1/(\cos x)^2)(C + x/2 + \sin 2x/4)
$$

In no way can I get this solution if $P(x)$ is $0$. But what is it then?

I tried getting $y$ through integration of the left side by $dx$, and then plugging in $x$ derived from that equation into the original linear differential equation, but that is not giving me the requested solution either.

I would appreciate any help provided.

Answer (score 2):

Calculating backwards, you get
$$
\cos^2(x)y=C+\frac x2 + \frac{\sin(2x)}4\\\implies
\cos^2(x)y'-2\sin(x)\cos(x)y(x)=\frac12(1+\cos(2x))=\cos^2x
$$
so that the normalized DE is
$$
\cos(x)y'(x)=2\sin(x)y(x)+\cos(x)
$$
Thus there is some loss of factors in the equation you reproduced.

Comment: I added a y beside 2sinx, assuming it was a textbook mistake that you noticed. However, even so I get the wrong solution.

I divide both parts by cosx, and get P(x) = -2tgx, and Q(x) = 1. Then I apply the formula for y (the one with e), but the solution is still incorrect...

Comment: This should give the integrating factor as $\exp(\int P(x)\,dx)=\cos^2(x)$ and then my differentiation steps backwards as integration steps. You might get different terms that are a constant away from the reference solution.